# Install4j : Executable writing to console return back if we press enter a second time

Tags: install4j

When Executable writes to console (using the -console option), if I press "enter" a second time, it bring me back to the command prompt even though Executable is still running in the background. How we can force it to output everything to the console and only when done should it return to command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer on windows is a GUI executable, it cannot make the console wait for the process to finish. There are two ways around this:

1) Select the "Windows console executable" property of the installer on the Installer->Screens & Actions step. Drawback: When starting the installer from the explorer, a console will be opened.

2) Start the installer on the command line like this:

```
cmd /c installer.exe -c
```